# How can I convert .txt to .rdb format

Tags: python

I have a .txt file containing radial velocity (rv) time-series containing two columns: 1st time and 2nd the rv. I need to import it to this webpage https://dace.unige.ch/radialVelocities/ , however it just accepts files in .rdb format (see the import tab on the page top right corner). I was unable to find information on how to make my .txt file a .rdb file or perhaps how I can create a .rdb file from python in the first place.

(if I am saying something non-sense excuse me, I am not familiar with this .rdb extension and there is little information online)

Comment: Where is this text file coming from? If it already contains data in [rdb format](https://github.com/sripathikrishnan/redis-rdb-tools/wiki/Redis-RDB-Dump-File-Format) you can simply change the file extension.

Comment: can you give us an example of what the .txt looks like?

Comment: I have edited the question so to clarify your guys points.

Comment: @DouglasRodriguesAlves what is that RDB format? You can't convert to it if you don't know what it is. A lot of applications use that extension. The tag you used is about an Oracle database. The first result in a google search for `rdb format` is [Redis RDB dump file format](https://github.com/sripathikrishnan/redis-rdb-tools/wiki/Redis-RDB-Dump-File-Format). The second about the Nintendo 64 ROM database

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos .rdb is a type of file extension, I have seen many web pages on google talking about .rdb files, however, none of them explain exactly how to create such a file. I have data and I need to store it in such a way (.rdb) that the website (dace.unige.ch) accepts my file.

Comment: @DouglasRodriguesAlves you're repeating the same things you wrote in the question. That doesn't make them any clearer. Yes, it's and extension used by many different formats. Which one do you want? If the format is something used by that site only you should probably ask them, or check their documentation

Comment: @DouglasRodriguesAlves if you google for `dace rdb` you'll find [this page](https://dace.unige.ch/statistics/) that allows you to download example files. Looks like that `rdb` file is nothing more than a tab-separated file, with *dashes* in the second line.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thank you, I really checked and looked for help on my own. these rdb files are nothing then just tab separated files. I managed to fix my files based on the example from dace webpage. great! I now have other problems but it is ok. I appreciate it!